# Send image stored in image field in body of Email sp_dbsend_mail

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, varchar

Database table has an image stored as `image` field- am I able to pull this image from the database ie pull as a variable in a stored procedure or do I have to use something like Crystal Reports?

I wanted to include it in an email that's sent but unsure if possible - now wanting complete solution if its possible just some pointers in the right direction

"To clarify -
I have a select query that is run through by cursor and sends an email to a customer when a delivery has been completed. this runs every 5 mins - i can extend the query to include the image column I have found BUT am unsure how I can get this to show as an image in the body of the email ( the image is the captured signature) this is run directly on the server and if easier the image sent as an attachment is fine. –"

Thanks in advance

Paul

Comment: **WHY** are you storing an image (binary data) in a **string** (`varchar`) column?? Doesn't make any sense whatsoever. If you have **binary** data - use a **binary** column type like `VARBINARY()` !

Comment: The problem with storing an image in a `varchar` is that this is not a true binary representation, but rather depends on the collation used. Any binary data should always be stored in one of the binary formats, e.g. `varbinary` (or `image` for really old SQL Server versions).

Comment: Just in case it's not clear from the last two comments - your binary data is almost certainly corrupted due to codepage changes to fit into the `VARCHAR` format, and it's highly unlikely that conversion back to `VARBINARY`/`IMAGE` will work without data loss (and an invalid image).

Comment: sorry wll clarify - this database wasnt designed/built by me - I am just trying to create an email asked by the company that use it! - however as you guys rightly say I have not investigated enough - it is varbinary but held in different table

Comment: Struggling to find a way of completing this. Is it possible to place image from sql table into an email that will be sent via sp_dbsend_mail? Either as an attachment or preferably actually in the body of the email?  Would I need to export as a file in one procedure then attach that file or can i incorporate all in one procedure. I have searche dhigh and low but struggling for a workable solution.

Comment: Sorry @TT - I have edited my post as I made a bad error on the data type I have since found the image field in a different table I can link that to my original query which pulls in other data as well that I am sending via a cursor to send_mail - the current job works v well but wanted to also show a picture (it is a signature captured from a PDA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation for [sp_send_dbmail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx), in specific following parameters:

---

> [ @query = ] 'query'
>
> Is a query to execute. The results of the query can be attached as a file, or included in the body of the e-mail message. The query is of type nvarchar(max), and can contain any valid Transact-SQL statements. Note that the query is executed in a separate session, so local variables in the script calling sp_send_dbmail are not available to the query.

---

> [ @execute_query_database = ] 'execute_query_database'
>
> Is the database context within which the stored procedure runs the query. The parameter is of type sysname, with a default of the current database. This parameter is only applicable if @query is specified.

---

> [ @attach_query_result_as_file = ] attach_query_result_as_file
>
> Specifies whether the result set of the query is returned as an attached file. attach_query_result_as_file is of type bit, with a default of 0.
>
> When the value is 0, the query results are included in the body of the e-mail message, after the contents of the @body parameter. When the value is 1, the results are returned as an attachment. This parameter is only applicable if @query is specified.

---

> [ @query_attachment_filename = ] query_attachment_filename
>
> Specifies the file name to use for the result set of the query attachment. query_attachment_filename is of type nvarchar(255), with a default of NULL. This parameter is ignored when attach_query_result is 0. When attach_query_result is 1 and this parameter is NULL, Database Mail creates an arbitrary filename.

---

So make a query selecting the appropriate image, and pass it to the `@query` parameter. Set appropriate values for the other parameters. Look in the documentation if other query-parameters apply in your case.

Comment: @PaulyboyUK You can send the image as an attachment this way. Isn't that something you can use?

Comment: yes i tried that before posting it just attaches a garbage file - not the image

Comment: @PaulyboyUK Edit your question with the statement you tried. I doubt that SQL Server changes the image when it attaches it to the mail. Are you sure you set all parameters correctly? There are more than the four I posted in this answer. Review **all** parameters pertaining to the query.

Comment: @PaulyboyUK You should also change the title of your question as it is no longer relevant to your case.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally got this sorted and working in with my other code - ended up being able to export via cursor and when finished delete the folder contents - whilst dbsendmail added the attachment I was also able to embed into body of the email - code as follows for anyone interested! - I know its far from perfect so any assistance on cleaning up is appreciated - true novice alert!!! Hope it makes sense what I was trying to do - @TT thanks for your efforts and sorry for a - not being clear - b - not being clear - c - blah blah!!! - BR Paul

```
DECLARE @IMG_PATH VARBINARY(MAX),
@TIMESTAMP VARCHAR(MAX),
@ObjectToken INT,
@MYdtDate NVARCHAR(50),
@MYemail NVARCHAR(50),
@MYszBlockCapitols NVARCHAR(50),
@MYdwJobnumber NVARCHAR(50),
@MYszDelpostCode NVARCHAR(50),
@MYszDelAddrName NVARCHAR(50),
@MYszJobOrderNum NVARCHAR(50),
@MYszDelAddr4 NVARCHAR(50),
@MYszAccCode NVARCHAR(20),
@MYdtTime NVARCHAR(10),
@body NVARCHAR(4000)



DECLARE C1 CURSOR READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT ISNULL(JobItem.dwJobNumber,' '), ISNULL(JobItem.szDelAddrName,' '), ISNULL(JobItem.szDelPostCode,' '), ISNULL(Signature.szBlockCapitols,' '), ISNULL(StirlingManager_Comp1.dbo.SalesAccounts.szReportText8,' '), Convert(varchar,Signature.dtDate,103) AS Date, Convert(varchar,Signature.dtDate,108)as Time, ISNULL(JobItem.szJobOrderNum,' '), ISNULL(JobItem.szDelAddr4,' '), ISNULL(JobItem.szAccCode,' '), ISNULL(dms_document.data,' ')
FROM         Transport_Comp1.dbo.JobItem INNER JOIN
                      Transport_Comp1.dbo.dms_document ON JobItem.dwJobItemId = dms_document.dwJobItemId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Transport_Comp1.dbo.Signature ON dms_document.id = Signature.dwDocumentIdFK LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      DocArchive_Comp1.dbo.dms_document AS dms_document_1 ON dms_document.id = dms_document_1.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      StirlingManager_Comp1.dbo.SalesAccounts ON JobItem.szAccCode = StirlingManager_Comp1.dbo.SalesAccounts.szAccountCode
WHERE     (Signature.dtDate > DATEADD(MINUTE, -800, GETUTCDATE())) AND (Signature.dtDate < DATEADD(SECOND, -0.001, GETUTCDATE())) AND (Signature.bArrived = 0) AND (StirlingManager_Comp1.dbo.SalesAccounts.szReportText8 > '')
OPEN C1

FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO
 @MYdwJobnumber, @MYszDelAddrName, @MYszDelPostCode, @MYszBlockCapitols, @MYemail, @MYdtDate, @MYdtTime,@MYszJobOrderNum, @MYszDelAddr4, @MYszAccCode, @IMG_PATH
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
        SET @TIMESTAMP = 'd:\Signatures-TMP\' + @MYdwJobnumber + '.bmp'
        EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
        EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1
        EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open'
        EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, @IMG_PATH
        EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @TIMESTAMP, 2
        EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close'
        EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken


SET @body='<html><body><p><img src="http://www.mycompany.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/mycompany.png" alt="" align="left"></p>
<br><br><br>
<p><span style="font-size: 9px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color: #0d3172;"><strong>My Company<br><span style="Century Gothic;">My Company address</span></span></p>
<br><br></strong>
<h1><span style="font-size: x-large; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #0d3172;">DELIVERY CONFIRMATION</span></h1>
<br>
<table style="border: 2px double #0d3172; color: #0d3172; font-size: 12pt; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; width: 800px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><span style="font-size: small;">YOUR REFERENCE</span></td>
        <td width="590"><span style="font-size: small;"><strong>' + @MYszJobOrderNum + '</strong></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span style="font-size: small;">DELIVERY TO</span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: small;"><strong>' + @MYszDelAddrName + '</strong></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span style="font-size: small;">TOWN</span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: small;"><strong>' + @MYszDelAddr4 + '</strong></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span style="font-size: small;">POSTCODE</span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: small;"><strong>' + @MYszDelPostCode + '</strong></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span style="font-size: small;">DELIVERY DATE</span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: small;"><strong>' + @MYdtDate + '</strong></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span style="font-size: small;">DELIVERY TIME</span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: small;"><strong>' + @MYdtTime + '</strong></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span style="font-size: small;">SIGNED FOR BY</span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: small;"><strong>' + @MYszBlockCapitols + '</strong></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span style="font-size: small;">YOUR ACCOUNT CODE</span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: small;"><strong>' + @MYszAccCode + '</strong></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span style="font-size: small;">OUR JOB NUMBER</span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size: small;"><strong>' + @MYdwJobnumber + '</strong></span></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br><br>

<p><span style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color: #0d3172;"><strong>DIGITAL SIGNATURE</p></strong></span>
<img src="cid:'+ @MydwJobNumber + '.bmp" /><p></p>

<p><span style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color: #0d3172;"><strong>Please contact our Customer Services Team if you have any questions or queries.</span></strong></span></p></body>
</html>'
                EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                @profile_name = 'SQL_Email',
                @recipients = @MYemail,
                @subject = 'EMAIL POD',            
                @file_attachments = @TIMESTAMP,
                @body=@body, 
                @body_format = 'HTML';
                print @body;    

      FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO
 @MYdwJobnumber, @MYszDelAddrName, @MYszDelPostCode, @MYszBlockCapitols, @MYemail, @MYdtDate, @MYdtTime,@MYszJobOrderNum, @MYszDelAddr4, @MYszAccCode, @IMG_PATH
END
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'del D:\Signatures-TMP\*.bmp'
CLOSE C1
DEALLOCATE C1
```